# Using 3D perception in opencv2

Tags: python, opencv, 3d, geometry

Can anyone please explain if it is possible, and if so how, to work with cv2.getPerspectiveTransform().

I have 3d information about my image: I know the length of a,b and also the ***Different*** heights of c,d,e,f and g. I made the height different to get more 3d information but if it isn't needed that will be preferable.

Ultimately I need to know where the pink dot really is in the rectangle after implementing the transform on my [x,y] position I get from the camera feed.

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "know where the pink dot really is in the rectangle?"  Do you mean that you know that it's in the a-b plane already and you want to know where in the plane it is?  If so, then that is possible.  If you don't know whether it's in the a-b plane or not then it's impossible to look solely at the 2D image plane (a'-b') and determine where it is in 3D space.

Comment: The idea is that I need to find the centre of the yellow circle. I have found its location in the image but because of the cylinder's height, what I found is not the real centre of the circle location on the plane (floor). Hopefully using some transformation will get me the bottom center of the cylinder from the top centre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you denote by C,D,E,F the positions of the four corners of the black polygon in the original image (each of them is a 2D point), and C',D',E',F' the positions of the corresponding points in your target image (probably (0,0), (a, 0), (a, b), (0, b)), M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform({C,D,E,F}, {C',D',E',F'}) is the perspective transformation from one polygon to the other.

Given the position G of **the vertical projection of g** onto the black polygon in the original image, you can compute its position in the target image as cv2.transform(G, M). This will return a point (x,y,z), where the last coordinate z is a normalizing term. This z is zero when your point would be "at infinity" in the target image. If z is not zero, the point you are looking for is (x/z, y/z).

If z is zero, your point is at infinity, in the direction of the support of vector (x, y) (think of the case where G would be at the intersection of the supporting lines of two opposite sides of the black polygon in the source image).

If you know that the heights of c,d,e,f,g are equal, these points are also coplanar, and the exact same method applies to c,d,e,f,g instead of C,D,E,F,G.

Comment: Camille, could you please explain in more details what is the z parameter? I mean when and why would it become 0? i tried making my image such that the cylinder can not block the view of any of the pilers. also, how do i use the height of the pilers?

Comment: In practice the z parameter should not be zero. Assuming your pillars have all the same size (and it is the same as the height of the cylinder), z=0 would happen when g in the source image appears to be at the intersection of lines (cd) and (ef), for example. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates for details.

Comment: I'm still not sure how do I use the heights of the pillars. Do i enter C,D,E,F points with the x,y read from the image and the z I already know? C= (50,100,10) D= (100, 130, 15) and so on?
and as for C' D' E' I use only a 2d expression?

Comment: The input points to the function cv2.getPerspectiveTransform() are 2D points: they represent the position of the points as they appear on your picture. The simplest setup for you would be if all pillars and the cylinder have the same height. Then, you would enter the 2D-coordinates (as they appear on your photograph) of the top of the pillars as input to the function cv2.getPerspectiveTransform().

Comment: Just a bit more information.. The X,Y point I get from cv2.transform(G,M) are the ones I should divide by z or the G(x,y) point itself?

Comment: cv2.transform(G,M) will return three coordinates (x,y,z), which are the homogenous coordinates of the point you are looking for, so that the cartesian coordinates of the point you are looking for are (x/z, y/z).

Comment: I only get x,y values after i use cv2.transform(G,M).
What am I missing? if i use (x,y) i get (x',y') but I don't get the normalising factor. If i try (x,y,1) i just get (x',y',1)